# How Do I Replace/Change The Heading Text Inside <h1></h1>, Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-heading

How do I change/replace the text: "Hello" using javascript to say "Goodbye" instead?

```
<h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis" id="title">
     <span class="pagetitle" >
            Hello
     </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: you are explicitly referring to javascript, but do consider using jQuery, it will make your javascript coding life a lot easier

Comment: Is the inner span really required? Are there more elements with `.pagetitle` ?

Comment: @DaniëlTulp Not to mention add pointless overhead for extremely simple tasks

Comment: If this is the only javascript task, sure, but I assume with most modern websites/applications, it is not and as the jQuery library is so widely used and CDN's are available and the minified package is very small, I never think twice about using it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle")[0].innerHTML = "Goodbye";
```

Here is [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9KBj/).

Comment: We don't know that it's the first one on the page - which this code is currently assuming (granted it should be from the name.... but...)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('title').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Goodbye';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to give legacy browsers the finger (preferable):

```
document.querySelector('#title .pagetitle').innerHTML = 'Goodbye';
```

Support:

```
Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)  Internet Explorer  Opera  Safari (WebKit)
1       3.5 (1.9.1)      8                  10     3.2 (525.3)
        bug 416317                                 WebKit bug 16587
```

See also: [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: well, it has the tag `html5`

Comment: Worth pushing the newer techniques :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle")[0].textContent = "Goodbye";
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pagetitle")[0].innerHTML = "Goodbye";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('title').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent = 'Goodbye';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('title').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Goodbye';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('title').getElementsByClassName("pagetitle")[0].textContent = "Goodbye";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('title').getElementsByClassName("pagetitle")[0].innerHTML = "Goodbye";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aLopOsa/1/edit)

Change by using **getElementsByTagName('span')**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Goodbye';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML is not recommended according to [XSS vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/), textContent is not supported by older version of browsers (ex. IE8). So will be better to create a TextNode

```
element = document.getElementByClassName("pagetitle");
txt = document.createTextNode("GoodBye");
element.appendChild(txt);
```